# CoreData Fetch Request crashes initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, core-data, fetch

I have json like this [here](https://gist.github.com/perlasivakrishna/b268062d006989d39dcaf74e0542d7a5), while trying to save decoded response from API it works, but while fetching it crashes.

[sample code](https://gist.github.com/perlasivakrishna/706a577bdd55fe45ae8176d7e4c0d143)

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<RouteResponse>(entityName: "RouteResponse")
    let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let details = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) // crashes here.
```

[image: How Data is saved]
[image]
[image: Relation ships here]
exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x6000000ac2a0> ,  threw while decoding a value. with userInfo of {
NSUnderlyingException = "-[OpenFinanceTest.Route initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002cd8980"

Comment: There is something wrong with a transformable attribute.

Comment: There is only two values in RouteResponse  model and both are transformable

Comment: Likely the value transformers (related to `NSCoding`) are missing. Rather than with transformable dictionaries you should deal with relationships, that's more database like and more efficient.

Comment: Do I need to conform to NSCoding protocol when I already subclassed to NSManagedObject. 

Also I could see that all the data is getting inserted in DataBase

Comment: `NSManagedObject` is not a protocol, it's a class. Yes, you have to encode the transformable attributes with `NSCoding` (which is different from `Codable`)

Comment: Ok,  Can u give me an example, how to do that, I have to save total json response to core Data and fetch back.  Please see updated question where my data is saved.

Comment: Once again it's highly recommended to prefer relationships over transforming the object. About transformable attributes please read the section [Configure and Implement a Non-Standard Data Type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/handling_different_data_types_in_core_data)

Comment: @vadian I l already have relationship like shown above, Do you mean once i set proper relationship, I don't  need To transforming object

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: It's super confusing, There is  NSSecureCoding Protocol also, not sure which one to implement in my case